# NextJS rewrite url to ends in .jpg

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I have an API endpoint `/api/thumbnail` which returns a JPEG image.

What I want is make this endpoint accepts `.jpg`, like this `/api/thumbnail.jpg`.

Is it possible using pure NextJS or I need to use `vercel.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change your file name from

`./pages/api/thumbnail.(js|ts)x?`

to

`./pages/api/thumbnail.jpg.(js|ts)x?`